# Code in method is not called completely

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, vs-android

I have a method in Java which is called from jni:

```
public static void CallDoSomething()
{
    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"A");
    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"B");
    something.DoSomething(); 
    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"C");
    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"D");
}
```

So, the first line is called, I get 'A' in the logcat, after that nothing. No 'B' or the log from `DoSomething()` or 'C' or 'D'. It is really weird. I cleaned the project, restarted the IDE, nothing helped. No exceptions are made and the app doesn't crash.

Why is the log file missing entries of `B`, `C`, and `D`?

Comment: Sounds like a cache issue. Restart everything and try again.

Comment: Maybe the `i` method is faulty? Does the method `CallDoSomething` return normally?

Comment: @McDermott this sounds very bizarre. Could be very stupid, but could you restart the machine itself? Sounds like something/somewhere has cached.

Comment: @Eugene You kind of copied my comment there :p

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀups I did not even notice that :) sorry

Comment: You don't happen to use GreenRobots EventBus, do you?

Comment: @JakubZaverka `CallDoSomething` doesn't get called. @KEYSER @Eugene I've restarted everything.

Comment: @McDermott If it isn't called then this is a completely different issue. Debug to find out why.

Comment: If CallDoSomething doesn't get called at all, then how do you end up with 'A' in the log?

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ I manually deleted all generated files, and it is working now. Somehow it stayed cached.